# AndroidManifiest.xml FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to test my project on my phone, but when I run with eclipse it runs into a `fileNotFoundException` on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I looked in my project and the file is clearly there:

```
/Project
    assets/
        ...
    bin/
        ...
    gen/
        ...
    res/
        ...
    src/
        com/
            ...
    .classpath
    .project
    AndroidManifest.xml
    default.properties
```

Comment: I usually find doing a File -> Refresh followed by a Project -> Clean in eclipse fixes things like this.

Comment: Make that as an answer, it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it official:
In Eclipse, do a File -> Refresh followed by a Project -> Clean to rebuild the project. I find the most common need to do this is when the gen/R.java file isn't being updated for some reason.